# I have trouble translating Turing machine language, can you help me break down language notation to English?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

My problem is I don't have many issues with creating a Turing machine state table when given a string such as 01101, my issue arises when I am presented with a problem which requires the Turing machine to recognize the language {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ 0}.

I have found this guide on a [similar problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-turing-machine-language-l-0n1n2n-n%E2%89%A51/) however I cannot grasp what is going on and what is required from the language statement. Any help in regards to how to read the specified language effectively would be appreciated.

Comment: The link contains a very detailed guide. I suggest implementing the machine on a simulator and running it to see how it works.

Comment: This is also, notably, probably _the_ most famous example of a non-regular language. Try implementing a simpler regular language first, such as $\{0^i 1^j \mid i, j \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $s$ is a symbol and $n$ is a natural number, "$s^n$" means "$s$ repeated $n$ times".  So you're being asked to recognize the language of all strings that consist of $n$ zeros followed by $n$ ones, for any possible value of $n\geq 0$.  That is, $\{\epsilon, 01, 0011, 000111, 00001111, \dots\}$, where $\epsilon$ denotes the empty string (some people write $\lambda$ for the empty string, instead).

Comment: Thank you for this answer it has definitely helped! Just wondering would 0101 be accepted by this language or must it always be a number of zeros equal to n followed by a number of ones equal to n?

Comment: @DiamondDude Is there any $n$ such that $0101$ consists of $n$ zeros followed by $n$ ones?